# python file name as parameter from array

Tags: python, file, file-io

I need to declare filenames in an array and pass them to **open with** method in python.File name needs to be sent as **parameter** from the array.
Please let me know if the code below is fine.

```
filenames= ["abc.txt", "def.txt", "ghi.txt"]
```

Code for iterating

```
for file in filenames

    with open(file,'r')
```

My expectation is to iterate through the filenames and open them like

```
with open('abc.txt', 'r') #for first run

with open('def.txt', 'r') #for second run

with open('ghi.txt', 'r') #for third run
```

Comment: Open them in a sequence, that is it?

Comment: I was going to edit your question but then it becomes answer :P. Adding `:` to `for file in filenames` should solve your issue.

Comment: You should not use `file` as a variable name, as it is a reserved word. Better use `file_` or something like that in such occasions.

Comment: Thanks Chris for editing the question and correcting it.

Comment: @SSRSeln were you able to solve this? You may accept the answer that helped you: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

```
filenames= ["abc.txt", "def.txt", "ghi.txt"]

for i in range(len(filenames)):
    with open(filenames[i], 'r') as fileObj:
        # do the rest
```

Or just:

```
for file in filenames:
    with open(file, 'r') as fileObj:
        fileObj.readlines()
        # do the rest
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
filenames= ["abc.txt", "def.txt", "ghi.txt"] 
for single_filename in filenames:
    with open(single_filename, 'r') as file_object:
        print file_object.readlines()
```

Comment: and what if I want something similar but my filenames is [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] (numbers) and with the same for loop I want to read 1.txt, 2.txt and so on?

Answer (score -1):

If your files are in the same location as the python program, the below snippet is a good reference.

```
filenames= ["abc.txt", "def.txt", "ghi.txt"]
for i in filenames:
    with open(i,"r"):
        #do something with files here
```

In case your files are located somewhere else, try providing the full path in the list. Or use a prefix like below:

```
filenames= ["abc.txt", "def.txt", "ghi.txt"]
path_prefix = <path here>
for i in filenames:
    with open(path_prefix + i,"r"):
        #do something with files here
```

Comment: Your second solution doesn't use `path_suffix`. Besides, always better to use `os.path.join` than simply adding `str`s.

Comment: i missed 'r' in the open block, and somehow edit is not being passed. Just make sure to add that if you use it.

Comment: read comment above. Also , i is not the iteration number, it is the file name as I have not used range(). Just because I called it i and not files, does not mean it is an integer :p